# how can you display an image on a gui using tk in python2.7

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i need away to be able to show an image when i run the python code in its gui form if possible. Also do i have to type in the folder name and file name in the code if you know the answer i tried pil all it did was save the image into a folder i want this on the gui

the code for the tk if it is necessary

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

toolbar = Frame(root)

# All the buttons in my program
b = Button(toolbar, text="Home", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="About-us", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Contact-us", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Travelling", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)


toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

# All the labels in my program
o = Label(root,text="Frank Anne",font =("Italic",18,"bold"))
o.pack()

toolbar1 = Frame(root)

o=Label(root,)
o.pack()


o=Label(root,text ="Age:                     27")
o.pack()

o=Label(root,text ="Address:                 71 strawberry lane, JU8 8TY")
o.pack()

toolbar1.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)









mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you just want to show an image using Tkinter?

To do this, you can use a Canvas widget filled with your image.

Here is an example:

```
can = Canvas(window, width=160, height=160, bg='white')
pic = PhotoImage(file='picture.jpg')
item = can.create_image(80, 80, image=pic)
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a canvas; you can also use a label widget.

Comment: I thought that was the "cleanest" way to make it.

Comment: My point was, saying somebody _needs_ to do something a certain way implies it is the only way, but in this case it's not the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if your looking to show an image inside a tk Canvas it needs to be a PPM/PGM or GIF:
[discussion from python.org](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-June/486811.html)

However if your looking to load a PPM, PGM or GIF:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("display a website image")
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file= r"C:\Some\Local\location\smile.gif")
cv = tk.Canvas()
cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
cv.create_image(10, 10, image=photo, anchor='nw')
root.mainloop()
```

This creates a frame, loads the image using tk.PhotoImage, then makes a canvas and puts the image onto the canvas.